# Ошибка 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Помогите! Я пытался подключиться к базе данных с помощью php кода

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$db_host = 'Мой хост';
$db_user = 'Мое имя пользователя';
$db_password = 'Мой пароль';
$db_name = 'Мое имя базы данных';

$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
if (!$link) {
    die('<p style="color:red">'.mysqli_connect_errno().' - '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>');
}

echo "<p>Вы подключились к MySQL!</p>";
```

Выдает ошибку:

> 2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'Мой хост' (61)

Смотрел про этот код [здесь](http://addphp.ru/materials/mysql/1_4.php).

Comment: А SQL-сервер-то у Вас запущен на компьютере 'Мой хост'?

Comment: Ну "Мой хост" - это не точное название, а так он не на компьютере, а на сервере(запущен).

Comment: А запущен он там на стандартном порту? И вообще, принимает ли он внешние соединения?

Comment: Если честно я в этом чайник. Не могли бы вы подсказать как это проверить? Если что использую phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Проверяйте параметры подключения к БД. 99% проблема в них.

Comment: В прошлом комментарии я говорил, что в подобном я чайник. Как проверить параметры подключения в phpMyAdmin.(Искать в гугле не помогло)

Answer (score 2):

1. проверяете правильно ли выставлены все логин, пароль, порт
2. проверяете доступны ли все привелегии для пользователя с под кого вы
   входите в самой БД
3. проверяете запущена ли MySQL на компьютере,
   или если это где-то с хостингом такая проблема то достаточно п.1
   и п.2
4. на хостингах бывает пункт, запрещено подключение с
   внешних машин -    разрешите если подключаетесь из вне
5. если делаете это на локалке приостановите брадмауер может лочить саму
   бд

Answer (score -1):

Привет. попробуй вот таким кодом. У меня работает нормально на OpenServer:

```
<?php
// Плагин подключения к базе данных
$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','user','pass','test_db');
if ( $connection == false)
{
echo 'Ошибка соединения к базе данных. Проверьте правильность ввода логина и пароля<br>';
echo mysqli_connect_error();
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Ну и чем этот вариант отличается от варианта ТС?

Comment: По крайней мере этот код я проверил на своем ПК

Comment: А у меня на ПК ваш код не работает. `2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'`

Comment: в БД создали таблицу test_db, и он не работает ?..

Comment: У меня не работает.

Comment: Если хочешь - скинь TeamViewer, ID, pass. Попробуем вместе подумать. На почту maksim.hizhnyak@gmail.com